# keybd_event showing weird behavior

Tags: c++, windows, winapi

I am trying to simulate enter key press using following code:

```
keybd_event(VK_RETURN , 0, 0, 0);
keybd_event(VK_RETURN , 0, KEYEVENTF_KEYUP, 0);
```

It works well in my 32 bit Windows XP OS but when I try in Windows 8 x64 machine, spacebar key press is simulated instead of enter key.

What should I do to get correct result?

I also tried using SendInput as shown below but i face the same problem.

```
void typeKey(short virtualKey)
{

 INPUT ip;
 ip.type = INPUT_KEYBOARD;
 ip.ki.wScan = 0; 
 ip.ki.time = 0;
 ip.ki.dwExtraInfo = 0;
 ip.ki.wVk = virtualKey; // virtual-key code for the character
 ip.ki.dwFlags = 0;
 SendInput(1, &ip, sizeof(INPUT));
 ip.ki.dwFlags = KEYEVENTF_KEYUP; // KEYEVENTF_KEYUP for key release
 SendInput(1, &ip, sizeof(INPUT));
}

//function call
typeKey(VK_RETURN);
```

Note: I am compiling a 32 bit executable on XP machine and using the same executable on Windows 8.

Comment: You are using the executable compiled on the XP machine and running it on the Windows 8 machine?  That is probably the problem (the fact that they are different OS and different architectures).  Try compiling on the Windows 8 machine and running that executable.

Comment: @AlexBrooks: that's *extremely* unlikely, SendInput and keyb_event haven't changed much since more than a decade, and even if he's running a 32 bit executable on a 64 bit machine Windows provides excellent backwards compatibility (since a very large part of the executables actually used in the wild are 32 bit stuff targeting XP).

Comment: @user221458: on what occasion are you simulating those keypresses? Maybe when the user is already pressing Enter?

Comment: No, user is not pressing any key.

Comment: @MatteoItalia are Windows XP and Windows 8 binary compatible?  If they are, then you are right and they should behave *exactly* the same. Otherwise behaviour is undefined.

Comment: What program are you using to check the keys entered?

Comment: I have tried various programs including notepad, wordpad, chrome etc.

Comment: @AlexBrooks: the point is that it's really unlikely that the compilation has anything to do with that, since here we are dealing with just a bunch of API calls (that would be the same however you compiled). It's true that the 32-bit compatibility layer does introduct some smokes and mirrors to fake a 32 bit OS, but replacing an enter key with a space makes no sense in that respect. My guess is simply that on his Windows 8 machine OP has installed an overzealous security suite which blocks synthesized enter keystrokes (that are used by some malware to simulate user interaction).

Comment: No special secuity software is installed. Only Windows Defender is running. Disabled it but the problem is not solved. Also checked all other processes which are running.

Comment: @user221458: just as an extra check: what if you send a tab (`VK_TAB`)?

Comment: VK_BACK works fine, i have not checked VK_TAB. Will check it and let you know.

Comment: VK_TAB also works perfectly.

Comment: Uhm, try to check if there are "strange" keyboard hooks... use the utility linked [here](http://shiftlock.wordpress.com/2011/06/22/windows-hooks-detector/) and check for WH_KEYBOARD_LL hooks.

Answer (score 0):

This is just an educated guess, but your old function uses argument types that differ in length from x86 to x64. That may be a problem. Listen to the documentation that says:

> Note  This function has been superseded. Use [SendInput](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646310%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) instead.

Comment: I have also tried SendInput but I get the same result.

Comment: keybd_event works for all other key presses which I have tried.

Comment: Can you post the example code using SendInput as an [SSCCE](http://www.sscce.org/)?

Answer (score 0):

I confirm your observation on 64-bit Windows 8.1. For some reason, VK_RETURN does not work correctly with `SendInput()`.

The solution seems to be to supply the scan code as well like this:

```
ip.ki.wScan = MapVirtualKey(virtualKey, MAPVK_VK_TO_VSC);
```